# Inserting many to many relation items with @Transaction in Android room database

Tags: transactions, insert, many-to-many, android-room

I am trying to insert multiple entries into an entity of a room database that are part of a many to many relation. This thus requires me to also insert a according entries into the cross-reference entity defining their many-to-many relationship.

To do this I am trying to use on single transaction in my Dao that combines all necessary insert functions.

As seen in the code below I am trying it in the following way:

- first insert my entires (in this case ingredients of a recipe) and grabbing their primary key IDs
- built a new List of cross-reference entries by combinining these IDs with the respective Recipe ID
- deleting any old cross-references for this recipe
- inserting the new cross-references for the ingredients just inserted

Here is the problem: it only works when I set breakpoints and go through it item by item. Otherwise it simply does not work. This makes me wonder whether it is somehow connected with the coroutine that I am running this in and some unintentional synchronous running of code? Is there any easier/ better practice way of inserting such a many to many relation. I am quite new to android room and SQlite queries and any help would be much appreciated.

Here are my code snippets

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface CoobookDao {

//Queries for Ingredients

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert_ingredients(ingredients:List<Ingredients>):List<Long>


//Queries for RecipesIngredientsCrossRef

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert_recipes_ingredients_crossrefs(recipes_ingredients_crossref: List<RecipesIngredientsCrossRef>)


    @Query("DELETE FROM RecipesIngredientsCrossRef WHERE recipeID = :recipeID")
    suspend fun delete_ingredientCrossRefs_for_recipe(recipeID:Int)


//Transactions

    @Transaction
    suspend fun insert_ingredients_for_recipe(ingredients:List<Ingredients>,recipeID:Int){
        val ingredients_list=insert_ingredients(ingredients)
        var recipes_ingredients_crossref = mutableListOf<RecipesIngredientsCrossRef>()
        for (ingredientID in ingredients_list){
            recipes_ingredients_crossref.add(RecipesIngredientsCrossRef(recipeID,ingredientID.toInt()))
        }
        delete_ingredientCrossRefs_for_recipe(recipeID)
        insert_recipes_ingredients_crossrefs(recipes_ingredients_crossref)
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
class CookbookRepository(private val dao: CoobookDao) {

    @WorkerThread
//functions for Ingredients
    suspend fun insert_ingredients_for_recipe(ingredients: List<Ingredients>,recipeID:Int) {
        dao.insert_ingredients_for_recipe(ingredients, recipeID)
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class CookbookViewModel (private val repository: CookbookRepository):ViewModel(){

    fun insert_ingredient_for_recipe(ingredients: List<Ingredients>,recipeID:Int)=viewModelScope.launch{
        repository.insert_ingredients_for_recipe(ingredients,recipeID)
    }
}
```

and in my code i then simply call the insert with:

```
CookbookViewModel.insert_ingredient_for_recipe(ingredient_list,recipeID)
```

Comment: To test your suspicion use `.allowMainThreadQueires` and run on the main thread rather than in a coroutine.

Comment: Thanks @MikeT that was a good suggestions. On mainthread it indeed works so it must somehow be connected to the coroutine. I still do not really know what exactly goes worng there, as the items in the suspend fuction should actually be run sequentially according to documentation. Anyway since I am only using it to actively write to the database, the mainthread blocking insertion is actually ok in that case. Thanks again!